# Is a python installation needed after creating an exe with embedded python using Pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I embedded pybind11 into my C++ project using CMake with the instructions found here: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html

Everything works fine and the exe compiles and runs, but I found that the exe will not run on any computer that does not already have python installed. Does that mean I did something incorrectly with my embedding? Or is that expected behavior?

Comment: Could you describe more about the observed behaviour? What is the error message you receive when you try to run the executable? The issue could be due to other reasons like the required shared libraries not being in the path.

Comment: When I try to run on a computer that does not have python installed, the exe process shows up in talk manager and then ends silently. No error messages.  After installing python on the computer, the exe runs without issue.  

I'm the CMakeLists.txt, I have the following:  

 project(example)  

add_subdirectory(pybind11)  

add_executable(example main.cpp)  
target_link_libraries(example PRIVATE   pybind11::embed)